# How do I href to a file without locking it?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, iis

I allow users to view a report on my IIS website with:

```
<a href="http://rence-pc/cure/Docs/MResult.pdf" alt="Error" target="_blank">Check Matching (Regularly through day)</a>
```

If a user leaves a report open - I am unable to update it.

Is there a flag to add to the above html such that user open a read-only copy?

Or is there another way to ensure multiple users can view the file but still leave it update-able?

Comment: all files served via HTTP are effectively read-only. The user downloads a copy onto their machine (the copy served by the webserver) not the original. By clicking on your link, they are not "leaving the report open" because they aren't interacting with the same physical copy of the file. Something else is causing your problem, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force to you user for download a copy of file.You can use the [download](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download)  attribute.

Example:

```
<a href="http://rence-pc/cure/Docs/MResult.pdf" download="MResult">Check Matching (Regularly through day)</a>
```

OR

```
<script>

var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
link.download = link.href;
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));

</script>
```